# Why does Facebook Debugger and Facebook's sharer.php URL display different things for the same exact URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you go to [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and enter in this exact URL and debug it, it scrapes everything fine, ie it gets the image, it gets the specific info to that date (regarding the song and move), etc.  So that's all good.

```
https://www.whenwasiconceived.com/results?month=01&day=1&year=1977
```

However, if you go to [that actual page](https://www.whenwasiconceived.com/results?month=01&day=1&year=1977) and click the Facebook share icon at the bottom, it doesn't bring up that same info in the sharer box.  Why won't it show the same specific info that the Facebook Debugger shows for the exact same URL? FYI, it's using the standard facebook sharer URL of:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.whenwasiconceived.com/results?month=01&day=1&year=1977
```

Seems so strange that Facebook's sharer URL and Facebook's debugger are displaying different things for the same exact URL.  I must be missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sharing a different URL than you think you do - because you neglected to properly URL-encode the parameter value.

```
sharer.php?u=https://www.whenwasiconceived.com/results?month=01&day=1&year=1977
                               value of parameter u ends here ^
```

You send `https://www.whenwasiconceived.com/results?month=01` as the URL to share, and then some additional parameters named `day` and `year`, that the sharer doesn’t care about and therefor ignores.

```
u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.whenwasiconceived.com%2Fresults%3Fmonth%3D01%26day%3D1%26year%3D1977
```

is the actual, properly encoded parameter you want to pass to the sharer.php script.